# What is the proper setup for spring defaultmessagelistener container on glassfish for redelivery after exception?

Tags: glassfish, spring-jms

I'm trying to setup spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer class to redeliver messages after an exception is thrown or session.rollback() is called.  I am also trying to get this running on glassfish 3.1.2 web profile.

When calling session.rollback() in the onMessage() method of my SessionAwareMessageListener, I get an exception with the message saying: **MessageDispatcher - [C4024]: The session is not transacted.**  I don't see this problem with ActiveMQ, but of course that configuration is different because I'm not using it in an application server.

Has anyone here gotten this working?  My configuration follows:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.jndicontext.url}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.state">com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">com.sun.enterprise.naming</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.connection.factory}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="jmsServiceQueue"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsServiceProducer"
      class="net.exchangesolutions.services.messaging.service.jms.JmsMessageServiceProducerImpl">
    <property name="serviceTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
    <property name="serviceDestination" ref="jmsServiceQueue"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myMessageListener"
      class="com.myorg.jms.MessageDispatcher"/>


<bean id="jmsServiceContainer"
   class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="destination" ref="jmsServiceQueue"/>
   <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener"/>
   <property name="errorHandler" ref="jmsErrorHandler" />
   <property name="receiveTimeout" value="180000"/>
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
   <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE"/>
   <property name="pubSubNoLocal" value="true"/>
   <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
   <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="2" />
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `acknowledge="auto"`, the message is acknowledged before listener execution, so the message is deleted from queue.

I have also achieved the DLQ scenario in Spring Application by doing the following changes to your code.

First, we set the acknowledge="transacted" (Since we want guaranteed redelivery in case of exception thrown and Trans acknowledgment for successful listener execution)

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge=" transacted">
```

Next, since we want to throw the `JMSException`, we are implementing `SessionAwareMessageListener`.

```
public class MyMessageQueueListener implements SessionAwareMessageListener {
    public void onMessage( Message message , Session session ) throws JMSException {
        //DO something
        if(success){
            //Do nothing – so the transaction acknowledged
        } else {
            //throw exception - So it redelivers
            throw new JMSException("..exception");
        } 
    }
}
```

I have tested this. This seems working fine.